# Kubernetes. Добавить пользователя админа

Tags: kubernetes

Помогите, пожалуйста с rbac.
Пытаюсь создать юзера с правами admin.

ClusterRole:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: admin-test
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  #
  # at the HTTP level, the name of the resource for accessing Secret
  # objects is "secrets"
  resources: ["all"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "list", "admin", "edit", "view"]
```

Cluster-role-binding

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: admin-test-global
subjects:
- kind: User
  name: user1
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: admin-test
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

После чего создаю config файл для kubectl с помощью:

```
kubeadm alpha kubeconfig user --client-name=user1
```

На выходе получаю:

```
(Forbidden): pods is forbidden: User "user1" cannot list resource "pods" in API group
```

Comment: так вроде же для доступа к подам нужно создавать не `ClusterRole`, а `Role`

Answer (score 0):

Тебе не нужно создавать РОЛЬ админа тк она уже есть по умолчанию

Необходимо сгенерить пользователя и повесить через RoleBinding пользователя на существующую роль.

(Чтобы сделать ограниченную роль нужно будет вникать в то какие resources нужны пользователю и описывать их в отдельной роли.)

Ниже листинг скрипта который создаёт пользователя (генерит сертификат) и предоставляет команду для настройки отдельного контекста под этого пользователя

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Created: mobilesfinks
#

function usage {
echo "Usage: $0 [K8S_USERNAME] [K8S_GROUP] [KUBECONTEXT]"
echo -e "\tK8S_USERNAME - kuber username for generate cert"
echo -e "\tK8S_GROUP - kuber groupname for generate cert"
echo -e "\tKUBECONTEXT - kuber context for cluster for generate cert"

echo -e "\nExample: ./create_k8s_user.sh SomeUser dev dc01 "
}

if [ $# -ne  3 ]
  then
    echo "Need 3 arguments"
    usage
    exit 1
fi

if [[ "$OSTYPE" == "linux-gnu"* ]]; then
  base64_args=' -w '
elif [[ "$OSTYPE" == "darwin"* ]]; then
  base64_args=''
else
  echo "Unknown OS."
  exit 1
fi


# Vars
export DIRECTORY=`dirname $0`
export K8S_USERNAME="$1"
export K8S_GROUP="$2"
export KUBECONTEXT="$3"
export USER_DIR="${DIRECTORY}/certs/${KUBECONTEXT}/${K8S_USERNAME}"

#debug
# echo "USER_DIR: ${USER_DIR}"

# Генерация запроса
function encode {

  cat $1 | base64 ${base64_args}
}
function gen_csr {
  mkdir -p ${USER_DIR}
  openssl genrsa -out ${USER_DIR}/${K8S_USERNAME}.key 2048
  openssl req -new -key ${USER_DIR}/${K8S_USERNAME}.key -out ${USER_DIR}/${K8S_USERNAME}.csr -subj "/CN=${K8S_USERNAME}/O=${K8S_GROUP}"\n
  encode ${USER_DIR}/${K8S_USERNAME}.csr #| base64 -
}

# генерим новый запрос только если ещё нет файла csr
if [ -f "${USER_DIR}"/${K8S_USERNAME}.csr ]; then
  export K8S_USERNAME_CSR_enc="$(encode ${USER_DIR}/${K8S_USERNAME}.csr)"
else
  export K8S_USERNAME_CSR_enc="$(gen_csr)"
fi

# Генерим запрос для кубера
cat ${DIRECTORY}/templates/k8s_csr.tmpl | envsubst > ${USER_DIR}/k8s_${K8S_USERNAME}-csr.yaml
# отправляем в кубер
kubectl --context ${KUBECONTEXT} apply  -f ${USER_DIR}/k8s_${K8S_USERNAME}-csr.yaml
# Подтвержаем сертификата нового пользователя
kubectl --context ${KUBECONTEXT} certificate approve ${K8S_USERNAME}-csr
# Вытаскиваем сертификат пользователя и сохраняем в файл
kubectl --context ${KUBECONTEXT} get csr ${K8S_USERNAME}-csr -o jsonpath='{.status.certificate}'|base64 --decode > ${USER_DIR}/${K8S_USERNAME}.crt

function print_cluster_conf {
  deftoken=$(kubectl --context ${KUBECONTEXT} get secrets | grep default-token | awk '{print $1}')
  ca_crt=$(kubectl --context ${KUBECONTEXT} get secrets ${deftoken} -o json | jq -r '.data["ca.crt"]')
  endpoint=$(kubectl --context ${KUBECONTEXT} config view -o jsonpath="{.clusters[?(@.name == \"${KUBECONTEXT}\")].cluster.server}")
  echo "
HOMEDIR=\$(getent passwd \"\$USER\" | cut -d: -f6)
  "
  echo -e "echo '$ca_crt' | base64 -d > \${HOMEDIR}/.kube/${KUBECONTEXT}_ca.crt \n"
  echo -e "kubectl config set-cluster ${KUBECONTEXT} --embed-certs=true --server=$endpoint --certificate-authority=\${HOMEDIR}/.kube/${KUBECONTEXT}_ca.crt"

}

function print_set_contex_params {
# У пользователя

USER_CERT_ENC=$( encode  ${USER_DIR}/${K8S_USERNAME}.crt)
USER_KEY_ENC=$(encode ${USER_DIR}/${K8S_USERNAME}.key)
echo "
HOMEDIR=\$(getent passwd \"\$USER\" | cut -d: -f6)

echo "${USER_CERT_ENC}" |base64 -d > \${HOMEDIR}/.kube/${KUBECONTEXT}-${K8S_USERNAME}.crt
echo "${USER_KEY_ENC}" |base64 -d > \${HOMEDIR}/.kube/${KUBECONTEXT}-${K8S_USERNAME}.key

kubectl config set-credentials ${K8S_USERNAME} --client-certificate=\${HOMEDIR}/.kube/${KUBECONTEXT}-${K8S_USERNAME}.crt --client-key=\${HOMEDIR}/.kube/${KUBECONTEXT}-${K8S_USERNAME}.key
kubectl config set-context ${K8S_USERNAME} --cluster=${KUBECONTEXT} --user=${K8S_USERNAME}
"
} # end function get sa



echo -e "#######################################################"
echo -e "####### Команды для добавления кластера ${KUBECONTEXT}"
echo -e "####### Выполнить у пользователя ######################"
echo -e "#######################################################"
print_cluster_conf
echo -e '\n'
echo -e "#######################################################"
echo -e "####### Команды для добавления контекста ${KUBECONTEXT}-${K8S_USERNAME}"
echo -e "####### Выполнить у пользователя ######################"
echo -e "#######################################################"
print_set_contex_params
```

После генерации пользователя добавляем примерно такой ClusterRoleBinding (RoleBinding)

```
---
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: allow-all_admins
subjects:
- kind: User
  name: SomeUser
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

Comment: Спасибо, уже разобрался. Сделал также, только без скрипта